# Following camera with javascript/html canvas for game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

```
    frameUpdate = ()=>{
        canvas = $("canvas")[0]
        c = canvas.getContext('2d')
        c.resetTransform()
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        LocalPlayer.Move();//if player press arrow keys, changes X any Y values of local player

        c.translate(LocalPlayer.X - (canvas.width/2), LocalPlayer.Y - (canvas.height/2));//not works

        LocalPlayer.Update();//draws Local Player at own X and Y position to canvas
        PList.Update();//draws other players at own X and Y position to canvas


       if (LocalPlayer) {socket.emit('sendplayer',LocalPlayer);}//sends LocalPlayer's data to server
        requestAnimationFrame(frameUpdate)
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(frameUpdate)
```

i want to make a game like io games with socket.io and html/canvas
but i cant make camera follows player, and i cant found any simple solution on internet
so if you can, i want tell me how it works and what is wrong on my code

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several tests with codepen i was solve my own problem myself

```
function update() {
  c.save();
  camerax = (canvas.width/2)-(playerx);
  cameray = (canvas.height/2)-(playery);
  mtt.innerText = "Camera Position:"+camerax+","+cameray+"\nPlayer Position:"+playerx+","+playery+"\nCanvas:"+canvas.width+","+canvas.height+"\n";
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.translate(camerax, cameray);

   c.fillStyle = 'green';
  c.fillRect(playerx-25, playery-25, 50, 50);
  c.restore();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```